# Read committed and transaction Error 1213: Deadlock

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions, deadlock, isolation-level

I have MySql 5.7 and following golang code that may be run concurrently:

```
tx := s.db.Begin()

if err := tx.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("DELETE FROM related_table WHERE id = %d " item.ID)).Error; err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
}

// Save is ORM method, it make inserts into 'related_table' from the first query 
if err := tx.Save(&item).Error; err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
}
```

I catch error during `tx.Save(&item)`

> Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

**The question is:**

How it possible that mysql transaction is not protected against deadlocks? Don't transactions run sequentially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select ... for update` is setting exclusive locks on the rows until the end of transaction

Just run following at the beginning of transaction:

```
tx.Exec("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE coupon_id = ? FOR UPDATE", item.ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

i can see something "Error; err != nil { tx.Rollback()" ; so i guess this means rollback on failure, right? ;so what happens if its a success; do you have to mention commit explictly; or its autocommit in your setup?